# Issue With Calculated DateTime Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula

I created Two Calculated Fields :

- The First Formula of Calculated Field `=TEXT([Created];"mmmm")`
  the Result is : First spring (Name Of Hejri Month in Hijri Format Arabic )
- The First Formula of Calculated Field `=TEXT([Created];"yyyy")`
  the Result is : 2014 (year in Gregorian Format )
  and when i make this Formula `=TEXT([Created];"mmm")` 
  the Result is : Ramadan  !!!??? It made me feel insane

Why is this ? it supposed to return 1435
Also When I open the item in DispForm.aspx its Appear as : created at  07/01/2014 11:00 AM , But When I Add Created Field To Default View of list , it's Appear as 06/03/35

Something else , in the Workflow it returns the value in Hijri Format , and I want to send email containing Date Field with Gregorian Format !!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why should it return 1435? You didn't create the item in the year 1435.

Comment: i created it in 6/3/1435

Comment: None of us were alive in the year 1435... I should specify that's by the Gregorian Calendar.

Comment: SP dates are actually counters and start counting at january 1st 1900 .. I am not sure.. but I don't think SP handles negative dates

Comment: This is an item created in the past , even the items that i created it today , calculated field return like this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DispForm.aspx is displaying the Gregorian date the item was created. The default view is using your regional dates.  The date calculated fields return Gregorian dates, so "yyyy" returns 2014 because that's the Gregorian year of the Created date. I don't think calculated field dates can be manipulated in other regions' calendars.

For your workflow, use a calculated field to return the Gregorian date `=TEXT([Created];"MM/dd/yyyy")` and return that field in your workflow.

[image]

Comment: =TEXT([Created];"mmmm") return "ربيع الأول" ) First spring  In Arabic !!!???

Comment: Don't use "mmmmm." Use `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: The comma in my answer should be a semi-colon for your region. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i want to return only year of created date as 1437 , because i have field with name Hejri year

Comment: i have four field ( year , month in Gregorian ) , ( year , month in Hejri ) , and its calculated and i get all result except year in hejri

Comment: What happens if you use a workflow to set a string variable to `Created` as Short Date? (adding screenshot to my answer)

Comment: its return the Short Date in Hejri Format Like this 06/03/35

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using This Formula :

- For Hejri Month Field  `=TEXT([Created];"mmmm")`
- For Gregorian  year Field `=TEXT([Created];"yyyy")`
- For Gregorian Month Field `=TEXT([Created];"mm")`
- For Hejri Year i used WorkFlow To Extract The First two litter From short Date   String of Created Field

and For  sending email containing Date Field with Gregorian Format , i created Calculated Field With this Formula `=TEXT([Created];"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")` and adding this Field to email body .

Comment: You should at least upvote my answer, since I'm the one who suggested you use Created Short Date